# Slide and combine data frame by fixed width intervals using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Although I know there're several ways to do, I'm stuck on how to slice and combine a data.frame by fixed width interval using dplyr. The input file is a speech-to-text transcription in this form:

```
     startTime endTime     word
1        0.0     1.9       Vabbè
2        1.9     2.3      quindi
3        2.3     2.3          ti
4        2.3     2.9       porto
5        2.9     3.8      niente
6        3.8     4.9       della
7        4.9     6.2 riferimenti
8        6.2     7.1           e
9        7.1     8.1        come
10       8.1     8.2          vi
```

In this form suitable to convert in a .srt subtitles file where all words in 3 seconds intervals are combined in strings, ie:

```
      startTime endTime word
1     0.0      2.9  Vabbè quindi ti porto
2     2.9      6.2  niente della riferimenti
3     6.2      8.2  e come vi
```

Reproducible data:

```
ex <- structure(list(startTime = c(0, 1.9, 2.3, 2.3, 2.9, 3.8, 4.9,6.2, 7.1, 8.1),
                 endTime = c(1.9, 2.3, 2.3, 2.9, 3.8, 4.9, 6.2,7.1, 8.1, 8.2),
                 word = c("Vabbè", "quindi", "ti", "porto", "niente","della", "riferimenti", "e", "come", "vi")),
            row.names = c(NA,10L), class = "data.frame")
```

How to do that with cut/split and dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to your desired output.

```
ex %>%
  mutate(group = floor(endTime / 3.5)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(startTime = min(startTime), 
            endTime = max(endTime), 
            text = paste(word, collapse = " ")) %>%
  select(-group)


# A tibble: 3 x 3
  startTime endTime text                    
      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                   
1       0       2.9 Vabbè quindi ti porto   
2       2.9     6.2 niente della riferimenti
3       6.2     8.2 e come vi
```

But honestly I struggelt with the three second interval. Because in your output the periode between start and end time is more than 3 seconds (see row 2 - the interval is 3.3 seconds). Therefore I expanded 3 seconds to 3.49 seconds.